# why I don't get the Latitude on my app? and what I should do to fix it?

Tags: android, api, google-api

I need to get to my app the Latitude on the TextView. so, I use in Location code, I use in android 5, and I puy my Key value, put the GPS and nothing happen.

so my code in MainActivity is:

```
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();

    txtOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtOutput);
}


@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(10); // Update location every second

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection has been suspend");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection has failed");
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, location.toString());
   // txtOutput.setText(location.toString());

   txtOutput.setText(Double.toString(location.getLatitude()));
```

so when I see my app I don't get the Latitude, what I should do???

thanks foe Help :)

Comment: Where are the `onStart` and `onStop` calls? https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

Comment: I add the methos in new answer..